# I need send props to other component but always fail I don't know reason for this

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I want to send props from app component to `Home` component.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    movie: [],
    tv: [],
  }

  getTrending = async (mediaType) => {
    let allTrinding = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending.${mediaType}/week?api_key=.....`);
    console.log(allTrinding);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTrending("movie");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/home" exact render={props => <Home {...props} movie={this.state.movie} />} />
          <Route path="/movie" element={<Movie />} />
          <Route path="/tv" element={<Tv />} />
        </Routes>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di2hY.png

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Please don't [use images for code, data structures or log files](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9078341)

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing props to routed components works just as anywhere else in React, simply pass the props you need. The `Route` component has only the `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, prop value.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/home" element={<Home movie={this.state.movie} />} />
  <Route path="/movie" element={<Movie />} />
  <Route path="/tv" element={<Tv />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: @AhmedFathy There's not much more to explain other than "render the component on the `element` prop" and "pass *that* component the props it needs". That warning about rendering an `Outlet` means the route is missing the `element` prop value.

Comment: this work but dont work when send props {history, match ect...}

Comment: @AhmedFathy `react-router@6` removed "route props", they don't exist. If you need to access what they used to provide then use the React hooks in the routed components. (useNavigate, useLocation, useParams)